# Draw flipped (mirrored) texture in Psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I am using Matlab and Psychtoolbox-3. I have created some texture, and now I need to draw it in mirrored orientation. I try to use

```
Screen('DrawTexture',win,tex,[],rect,[180]);
```

syntax, by as expected it gives me rotated.

**Is there any way to do it in Psychtoolbox?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the psychtoolbox, but assuming that you can get an underlying numeric matrix that corresponds to tex, in MATLAB, you can mirror/reflect any matrix using:

```
newMatrixHorizontallyReflected = fliplr(oldMatrix);
```

or

```
newMatrixVerticallyReflected = flipud(oldMatrix);
```

I'll assume you can either modify the data that underlies the existing texture or create a new texture with reflected data.

Comment: This would work for static textures, but I have OpenGL texture

Comment: Is it possible to provide a geometric transformation matrix somewhere in this Psychtoolbox toolchain? If they will let you do that, then you can specify reflection in the transformation matrix.